# Drag 'file' out of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag

I need to drag out a cell from a datagridview to desktop, once that happens, I need to find out the directory in where it was dragged into and in which row the cell was. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a codeproject article designed for a different purpose but it implements the drag feature in a datagrid view. So, I suggest that you check it out. Here 's the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12539/How-to-drag-information-from-a-DataGridView-contro).